# does class reference itself static anti pattern in prism

Tags: c#, design-patterns, prism

I have an application and my desing approach look like this:

```
class Manager
{
    public int State;

    static Manager _instance = null;
    public static Manager Instance
    {
        get { return _instance; }
        set
        {
            if (_instance == value)
                return;
            _instance = value;
        }
    }

    public Manager()
    {
        State = 0;
        Instance=this;
    }
}
class Module1
{
    public void GetState()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Manager.Instance.State);
    }
}
class Module2
{
    public void GetState()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Manager.Instance.State);
    }
}
class Module3
{
    public void GetState()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Manager.Instance.State);
    }
}
```

Manager class already registered in Bootstrapper like :

```
 protected override void ConfigureContainer()
 {
       base.ConfigureContainer();
       Container.RegisterType<Manager>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
 }
 protected override void InitializeModules()
 {
      Manager man= Container.Resolve<Manager>();
 }
```

Question is do I need to define my manager object as static in its field to be able to reach its state? Or this is anti pattern or bad for performance?

Comment: Do you anticipate having more than one Manager instance?  If not, use the Singleton pattern.  See http://csharpindepth.com/articles/general/singleton.aspx for a good discussion.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to have only a single instance of Manager class, it's better to register it in the container with [RegisterInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee649707.aspx) method. That way, whenever your class is injected into dependent code, it is always the same instance of a class. In that case you need no static parameters in you class, and later you can make your code less coupled by introducing interfaces. Then client classes will get, say, IModule parameter, not a concrete Module object, and the container will ensure that during the lifetime of the application, the IModule implementation object is always the same instance.